# Inverse polynomial map

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, inverse

I would like to find a method compute the (local) inverse (near $(0,0,0)$) of the map
$$
\phi : \mathbb{R}^3\ni (x_1,x_2,x_3) \mapsto (x_1,(1+x_2)x_3,(1+x_1)(1+x_2)x_2+x_1x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3.
$$
And the method should be quite general for all polynomial maps.

I am reading some introduction to Gröbner basis which could resolve this problem.

This method is global and since I want only local inverse, I wonder if there is other methods for such local problems.

With Mathematica, the routine *Solve* gives very bad results and I don't know any algebra methods to solve such polynomial systems, so I am looking towards maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's set

\begin{align}
A&=x_1\\
B&=(1+x_2)x_3\\
C&=(1+x_1)(1+x_2)x_2+x_1x_3
\end{align}

Now we are to find $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of $A,B,C$. We already have $x_1=A$, so we may write $C=(1+A)(1+x_2)x_2+Ax_3$, and together with $x_2=\tfrac{1}{x_3}B-1$, we have

$$C=(1+A)(1+\tfrac{1}{x_3}B-1)(\tfrac{1}{x_3}B-1)+Ax_3$$

which we can rewrite to

$$0=Ax_3^3-C\cdot x_3^2-(1+A)Bx_3+(1+A)B^2$$

This is merely third-degree and thus solvable; I will spare you the expression, but you can take a look at the monster at [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+Ax%5E3-Cx%5E2-(1%2BA)Bx%2B(1%2BA)B%5E2%3D0). Now we found $x_1$ and $x_3$, and so we are left with $x_2=\tfrac1{x_3}B-1$, so we know $x_2$ as well.

Not a very pretty solution, but a solution nevertheless.